# How to use a variable in a link HTML email

Tags: url, hyperlink

I'm trying to create an email sender with a link for users to click but I don't want them to see the actual link but rather see "Click Here". I have a code but I don't know exactly how to make it work (see code below):

```
$message    .= "<tr><td><strong>Url:</strong> </td><td>" '<a href=".$urlpath.">Send Mail</a>'  "</td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$message    .= '<tr><td><strong>Url:</strong> </td><td>'; 
$message    .= '<a href="'.$urlpath.'">'; 
$message    .= '<span style="color: #000000;">Send Mail</span></a></td></tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you're using php, is that right? Also, I'm not sure if I understand what you're wanting but this seems like a simple fix for what I think you want.

```
<a href = "mailto:email@ExampleMail.com">
Click Here
</a>
```

This will open the users default mail application and fill in the To: field for them.

Comment: @ Yeet thanks for your reply, I have a form which generates an email to be sent to client. The form generates a link depending on user selection, this link is now a variable ($urlpath) to be used in php. It work well but recipients will see the actual link insted of just a cleaner way of just "Click Here". Hope that make sense.

Comment: in your original var declaration, what does the .= do?? Other than that it seems like a contatination problem so try this          $message = "<tr><td><strong>Url:</strong> </td><td><a href=".$urlpath.">Send Mail</a></td></tr>";

Comment: Thanks for the help! I figured it out...I think! I played with placing single and double quotes and seem to be working.

Comment: $message .= '<tr><td><strong>Url:</strong> </td><td>';
$message .= '<a href="'.$urlpath.'">';
$message .= '<span style="color: #000000;">Send Mail</span></a></td></tr>';